# How would you write a rollmean in spark?

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I am new using `Spark` and I have to deal with huge timeseries. For a benchmark, I need to compare several implementations of a rollmean. In iterating mode with numpy, it is really fast (0.055970s for 1,000,000 points and window=3). I wrote a new-comer-in-pyspark version of a rollmean, and results are horrible (several seconds for the same vector).
For example, I have

```
ts_list = ["key1", "key2",...,"keyN"]
seq = sc.parallelize(ts_list)
d = {"key1": [1, 2, 3, ...], "key2": [1, 2, 3, ...]}
```

My processing:

```
s = seq.map(lambda s: (s, d[s]))\
.flatMap(lambda s: [(s[0], sum(elem)/k) for elem in rolling_window(np.array(s[1]), k)])\
.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: list(x))\
.collect()
```

I think that using a worker for k points is worthless. I suspect communications between master and workers are time-consumming. Also I wonder wether I should load data in the driver with parallelize or inside workers?

What if my vectors have trillions of points?

Comment: Well, You use  `groupBy` and that method consumes a lot of time, because it requires moving the data among all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

A subjective list of issues:

- using `flatMap` followed by `groupByKey` followed by `mapValues` doesn't makes sense at all. It is more expensive than required and in general (not here) doesn't provide any guarantees about the order. Instead just use `mapValues` to apply required logic:

  ```
  def rolling_mean(xs):
      ...

  rdd.mapValues(rolling_mean)
  ```
- creating NumPy arrays is expensive. If these are small the overhead can become rather substantial. Since you didn't provide an implementation of the `rolling_window` it is possible perform meaningful tests but in general if you don't use `NumPy` arrays from the beginning `sliding_window` over plain `list` or built-in `array` should be faster
- data loading:

  > whether I should load data in the driver with parallelize or inside workers?

  If it is possible you should always load data on the workers not pass from the driver. The latter option is useful mostly form testing and prototyping and introduces a serious IO bottleneck in your program. Moreover if data fits in the memory of a single machine distributing trivial computations is rather unlikely to provide any benefits.

  That being said if you decide to `parallelize` do it smart.

  ```
  sc.parallelize(d)
  ```

  It doesn't require passing a complete copy of `d` to each executor.
- last but not least have realistic expectations. If task is relatively cheap like here then the total cost will be driven but other factors like network IO, local socket communication, serialization, deserialization and general bookkeeping

Comment: Thank you for this constructive answer. I know see my lack of knowledge in Spark, I'll work on it ! I ended up doing: `result = seq.map(lambda s: (s,load_vector(s))).mapValues(lambda x: rollmean_calc(x, 3)).collect()`